# What is the point of the <Directory / > definition in apache configurations?

Tags: apache-2.2

I noticed that lots of example apache configuration files (and the one that came with my installation) have a block like:

    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None

But I can't understand or find an explanation of what this is for. I mean, what would the web server be doing in any directory other than the document root?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<Directory />` doesn't actually refer to the document root, it refers to the *filesystem* root. So creating a `<Directory />` block is a way to specify directives that apply to all files and directories anywhere on the server. It basically serves as a default setting.

The idea is, you don't want someone to be able to hack your server by, for example, somehow uploading an .htaccess file, just because you forgot to disable .htaccess files in some directory. So you start by disabling .htaccess files *everywhere*, then you don't have to worry about it. You can still enable them where you need them with `AllowOverride` directives for specific directories. Same goes for the `Options`: one of them is `ExecCGI`, which allows execution of CGI scripts in a particular directory. Obviously you don't want any random program on your system to be runnable as a CGI script; you want to keep them in a particular directory set up just for that purpose. So leaving `ExecCGI` out of `Options` in a `<Directory />` block disables CGI execution for the entire filesystem, then you can just enable it for the directories you want it in.

There are some ways in which content can be generated that isn't from a file on the filesystem, though... like `mod_status`, which dynamically creates a report of what the server is doing. Something like that wouldn't be affected by `<Directory />` blocks. So if you have directives that aren't file-specific that you really want to apply to the *whole* server (everything it serves, that is), you can use `<Location />`.

Comment: And if that's not explanation enough, http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#directory

Comment: I see... that's a good answer, thanks. I did know that Directory / was the filesystem root -- in fact that is why I was confused: I was assuming that it was impossible for anything to be touched outside of the document root in any case. But I forgot about cgi and such. Am right though in saying that even without this Directory / block it is not possible to request a file relative to the doc root like example.com/../../somethingsecret.txt?

Comment: Oh, a somewhat related question, whats with the /usr/share/doc/ stuff, can I delete that?

Comment: @ben (2 comments up): actually it might be possible. Most modern web servers guard against using `../` in a URL, but there are other ways to access files outside the document root, like symlinks and tilde mappings. Read through the page Chris linked to and you'll see some examples. And the files in `/usr/share/doc/` are just documentation files, you can delete them if you want (although maybe you'd rather move them to another folder instead so you still have them accessible).